# Google Api Error: forbidden: APK is not a valid ZIP archive while upload APK to playstore via API

Tags: android, azure-devops, google-play-developer-api

Today our Azure pipeline process failed to upload the APK to the Google Play Store with the following error in upload_to_play_store:

```
Found main APK to upload: D:/a/r1/a/Mobile App Builder/drop/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk 
APK is not a valid ZIP archive while upload APK to playstore via API
```

I am using Google Play - Release pipeline step.
Version info: `ms-vsclient.google-play.google-play-release.GooglePlayRelease@3`

There has been no change to the codebase since the last successful update builds, There may Google has changed something in their API side.

Comment: Also running into this error. I've looked through the deployment logs and nothing in the request payload is different between uploads that were succeeding on 10/07/2020. So assuming that something has changed somewhere, but no idea what :(

Comment: We are using Pipelines on Bitbucket and are experiencing the same thing. Using Fastlane locally I run into the same issue

Comment: Pretty sure it's a change in the Google API (or related). I get a similar error using Fastlane to deploy a native android app. Also tried with a build that succeeded 2 weeks ago - same error. "Google Api Error: forbidden: APK is not a valid ZIP archive". I don't remember updating the SDK or build tools locally.

Comment: Am also running into this error, Am using FastLane and circle ci for my pipeline.

Comment: Me too in CI. Fastlane's upload_to_play_store is failing. I think some changes were made on Google side.

Comment: I was trying to find the right place to get help. Didn't find a matching "Component" in issuetracker.google.com, but maybe "Google Play developer support" will do: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994

Comment: It has been fixed just now

Comment: Indeed, it has been fixed on Google's side. Tried it with a couple of apps.

Comment: Found this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google Api Error: forbidden: APK is not a valid ZIP archive while upload APK to playstore via API

This is an issue on Google's side. This issue has been fixed more than ten hours ago (as of my post answer).

At present, I could upload our APK successfully from Azure devops.

Please check if you still have this issue.

If you still have this issue, please let me know for free. Or you can re-open the ticket: [Issues 16721](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16721).